# Cannot open include file 'thread'

Tags: c++, multithreading, linker, include, 64-bit

I'm trying to use a threaded function for a parallel loop in a C++ program but I can't `include <thread>`, it keeps giving me the error

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'thread': No such file or directory
```

I'm running visual studio 2010 express, x64 (with x64 compiler options) and I believe I'm running the newest version of everything (Windows SDK 7.1) but I can't find an option in the props page for compiler version. (closest i found was Platform Toolset which is set to v100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler does not support C++11, so you need to upgrade/change the compiler. It seems that VS2012 supports it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx.

> As for the C++11 Standard Library, we don't have a pretty table of features, but Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012 does implement it (...)
> **New headers**: atomic, chrono, condition_variable, future, mutex, ratio, scoped_allocator, and **thread**.

Few more links about C++11 support:

http://cpprocks.com/c11-compiler-support-shootout-visual-studio-gcc-clang-intel/

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=118165827

Comment: So theres no way to use C++11 in VS2010?

Comment: Most part of it - no. You may use `boost::thread`, for example, but you may want to upgrade to VS2012.

Comment: @Arhowk VS2010 supports a decent-ish subset of C++11; here's a handy [compiler support table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport). VS 2010 is MSVC 10.0