# Qt Creator cannot find c++ ratio library?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I want to use the C++ template `Ratio` which is exhibited in [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ratio/ratio/) example. So I included the `ratio` library in the Qt program I'm writing in the QtCreator IDE, but it cannot find it. What should I do to enable the usage of that libary? Do Qt have its own template or function similar to the `Ratio` template?

Comment: how do you add library?

Comment: Okay, I'm kinda naive in programming any ways, so if I used the wrong words, forgive me :D. All I tried is writing `#include <ratio>` like in the link I showed, but Qt Creator can't find it :(.

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11 (or at least this part of it)?

Comment: I'm using MSVC++ Compiler 2010 SP1 standard, does it support C++11. I'm sorry, I'm not sure :(.

Comment: what error is shown to you? is it #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard ?

Comment: NO! It just says, C1083: Cannot open include file: "ratio": No such file or directory.

Comment: look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367147/cannot-open-include-file-thread)

Answer (score 0):

add following line to your .pro file

```
CONFIG += c++11
```